# Reload table view but don't move the viewport iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view which is updated based on the results from API. The table view has a large custom cell which takes almost half of the screen. The cells can be ordered by the user with a custom button. In average I will have between 10-15 cells inside the table and my big issue is when user clicks to move the very bottom cell by 1 point the reloadData will refresh the entire table and move the view port to the top meaning that the user will have to scroll to the end again which is terrible user experience. Is there a way to refresh table view but with keeping the position before the reload or would it be useful to consider using custom scroll which would be called after the table is populated. I'm writing the application in Swift, APIs are handled using Alamofire, custom cell has a separate XIB file and table view is inside my view controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the `contentOffset` then restore it after you `reloadData`

```
let contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset

tableView.reloadData()

tableView.contentOffset = contentOffset
```

Comment: I didn't know about the contentOffset property until today which is why I'll mark this as the correct answer because I really like the possibility of modifying the Y and being specific about the value, although the answer from @Das is perfectly correct as well and in reality potentially more useful because it comes with a handy animation right out of the box.

Comment: @NerminSehic note there's also a setContentOffset method that also takes an animated flag

Answer (score 3):

You would be better off saving the indexPath and then calling tableView.reloadData and then scrolling to the saved position as follows

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```